# how to override the .create() method inside a generic view (example: ListCreateAPIView) in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I wanted to override the create method in class-based view which implements the `ListCreateAPIView` , not generally while overriding  methods like the `get_queryset(self)` method, the requests, the url `**kwargs` are accessed from `self`, but I wanted to override the `.create()` method of  the `CreateModelMixin`, so I took a look at the code to find the signature as `create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` what does django pass in the `**kwargs, *args` of  this function? are these url `**kwargs` by any chance? How do I go about overriding the create method in the generic view asthe `request` in any function of the generic view is accessed from the `self` but the signature of the create function explicitly  requires a request argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following is DRF [ListCreateAPIView](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a251b9379200420062cad9e3c68fde7c0e6b3fdc/rest_framework/generics.py#L234-L244), as you can see `*args, **kwargs` are directly passing down from standard `post` method:

```
class ListCreateAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for listing a queryset or creating a model instance.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now, talking about overriding `create` from `CreateModelMixin`, you can simply override it as:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class YourWonderfulView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = YourModelClass.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs): # don't need to `self.request` since `request` is available as a parameter.

        # your custom implementation goes here

        return Response(response) # `response` is your custom response – e.g. dict, list, list of dicts etc
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Even though I don't need to use 'self.request' , I can still use it inside the create() function right?  as self is a YourWonderFulView object and hence should have attributes like request, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, you should be using `request` from parameters. Please accept this as an answer if this answers your question Or let me know if anything is unclear, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework import generics

from tasks.models import Task
from tasks.serializers import TaskSerializer


class TaskList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        # your implementation
        return Response(response)
```